# Rendering content of MTRC (markdown-to-react-components) saved in a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I have contents saved in a database which is generated from [markdown-to-react-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-react-components) as `MTRC(content).tree`

How can it be rendered. I've tried several methods including dangerouslyInsertHTML which I don't think makes sense since this a a collection of components. Thanks for the support in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Use [React-Markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).**

Usage:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactMarkdown = require('react-markdown');

var input = '# This is a header\n\nAnd this is a paragraph';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactMarkdown source={input} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Check [this markdown](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbeaudru/modern-js-cheatsheet/master/README.md) which is rendered **[here](http://share.mushfiqweb.com/JsCheatSheet)** using React-markdown.